# If you get invited to share a Google Play Android Developer Console do you have to pay aswell?

Tags: android, google-account

Google just opened up for sharing a developer console on android.

But if the account owner invites a person to join the developer console, does this person have to pay the 25$ and register as a developer before he/she can access the share developer console?

So far im unable to find the answer in the documentation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you pay 25$ for the developer account, not for person. You may invite other person to your developer console for free.

Comment: Thanks. It seams that you just have to wait half an hour for developer console to update your rights!

Comment: My friend invited me but when i click confirmation link it not opening only page loading continues and nothing is come.
Other sites opening quick but it hangs what should i do ?

Comment: @NabeelSaleem have you sold a problem? Try to resend an invite or consult with google support to fix a problem

Comment: i just changed my browser and it worked.

Comment: What steps I need to follow on successful invitation acceptance? It shows dashboard with 3-4 steps. What should I do then after? Please help

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure but

> The account owner can email an invitation to anyone; when they accept it, they’ll need to use a Google account to sign in.

sounds like other people will only need a google account, not a paid market account.